# Django username not displaying at all

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-authentication

I am an absolute beginner in Django. I have followed this tutorial:
http://www.rdegges.com/user-authentication-with-django/

And after few changes managed to get it working on newer version.
There is only one problem. After logging in, it says:

```
<h2>Welcome, {{ user.username }}</h2>
```

which should display the username of currently logged user.
Even though everything works, and I am being logged and transfered to this website, it just says : "Hello, " and generates nothing in the place of `{{ user.username }}`. Anyone knows what I might be missing?

Comment: do you have "django.core.context_processors.auth" in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS at your project's setting.py?

Comment: I added django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth because the one you propose is supposed to work for 1.2 and lower. Anyway, it still didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Try enabling `'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'` in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, but remember to put it BEFORE `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'`

Comment: Unfortunately, it is like that by default.

Comment: Are you sure you are loged in? try with only {{ user }} to see what happen

Comment: Still nothing. I uploaded my project to Dropbox, can you please check it? https://db.tt/gJbry9ti Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved your problem, the matter is about `render_to_response` and `django.template.RequestContext` the file `uploader/main/views.py` should look like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
rom django.template import RequestContext

@login_required
def main_main_page(request):
    return render_to_response('main/index.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Also an advice: unify your indents i.e. replace `tab` character by four spaces

Comment: Thank you for your tips and for solving my problem. It works! :)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** As long as you have "django.core.context_processors.auth" in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in your project's settings, you do not need to add request to refer to authenticated users in a template.

Your core issue was passing the request to the template via the context_instance that @juliocesar describes in his answer.

**Original answer:**

Try

```
<h2>Welcome, {{ request.user.username }}</h2>
```

The view in the tutorial doesn't appear to define and return the 'user' variable to the template, but you can access an authenticated user's information within request.

Comment: Anyway, can you guide me on how to create a template for user? request is not working, but maybe that way will do..?

Comment: -1 @lightstrike "doesn't appear to define and return the 'user' variable to the template" it is not necessary to display `user` in templates, just by adding `django.core.context_processors.auth` as @AlexParakhnevich comments on answer

Comment: @juliocesar You're totally right, my bad. All this time I've been using request.user...

Comment: @Fengson - juliocesar figured it out for you, I was able to confirm that fixes your issue. Make sure to accept his answer after you confirm it works for you! :-)